# How to make Visual C++ solution to not remove one project when start build another

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

I've got two projects in solution, library and executable.

First I build library but then when I start build another project it cleans library even when library files is in different folder and should not anyhow conflict with it.

How to say to not remove library by building my executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your executable depends on your library, the library will be automatically cleaned when cleaning or regenerating the executable.
It will not be cleaned if only generating the executable (not regenerating), which will only compile modifications since the last build.

If your executable does not depend on your library, the library should not be cleaned.
If this is really the case, you can try to build the executable by right clicking on the project located in the solution explorer.

Comment: maybe that's because I always use "rebuild" ?

Comment: maybe. Rebuild = clean + build

Comment: but this clean is really strange :P